# SQL Multiple WHERE's assigns a new table column

Tags: sql, select, sum, where-clause, multiple-instances

I'm having some problems due to my lack of experience in the language, would like your help...

I want the code to return the table as in the example below:

```
T01 --  T02 -- T03
23,00  32,00  43,00
```

So, heres my code:

```
SELECT
SUM([TOTAL $]) AS T01
FROM PFIN_base
WHERE [COORD] = 'alfa'
UNION
SELECT
SUM([TOTAL $]) AS T02
FROM PFIN_base
WHERE [COORD] = 'beta'
UNION
SELECT 
SUM([TOTAL $]) AS T03
FROM PFIN_base
WHERE [COORD] = 'gama'
```

This code returns the following result:

```
T01
23,00
32,00
43,00
```

How can i get the desired result?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when coord = 'alfa' then [TOTAL $] end) as T01,
       sum(case when coord = 'beta' then [TOTAL $] end) as T02,
       sum(case when coord = 'gamma' then [TOTAL $] end) as T03
from PFin_base
```